# How to perform pattern matching in R from reverse direction?

Tags: regex, r

I have an object called `mystring`. I want to remove the character by matching the first delimiter "_" from backward direction and get the `result`.

```
mystring<- c("apple_tar", "banana_bag_cool", "mango_mellow_yellow_sweet")
```

result

```
"apple"  "banana_bag"   "mango_mellow_yellow"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A similar approach is to separate each string into two groups and just exctract the first one

```
sub("(.*)(_.*)", "\\1", mystring)
## [1] "apple"               "banana_bag"          "mango_mellow_yellow"
```

`.*` will match anything and put it into the first group until it will encounter the last `_` and put everything on into the second group. This approach gives you a bit more control because you can select either group at your will by specifying `\\1` or `\\2`

Answer (score 2):

We can use `sub` to match an underscore(`_`) followed by one or more characters upto the end of the string (`$`) that is not an underscore (`[^_]`), and replace it by `''`.

```
 sub('_[^_]+$', '', mystring)
 #[1] "apple"               "banana_bag"          "mango_mellow_yellow"
```

Or another option is `str_extract`, where we extract the characters succeeded by underscore followed by one or more characters that is not an underscore until the end of the string.  Here, we use the lookaround (`(?=_[^_]+$)`).

```
 library(stringr)
 str_extract(mystring, '.*(?=_[^_]+$)')
 #[1] "apple"               "banana_bag"          "mango_mellow_yellow"
```

Comment: Could you explain this please: "_[^_]+$"

Comment: @MAPK Updated with some explanations